# The Oracle 10G SQL DB

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

i want to insert ,delete, select and update in a single procedure using array. means If i want to prees 1 it insert the data and this will continue till update that means 1 for insert 2 for delete 3 for select and 4 for update please suggest me.

thank you

Comment: You need to start with a SQL Book - https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Oracle-SQL-Plus/dp/1590594487

Comment: 1. look for a tutorial and learn 2. make your own attempt to solve your problem 3. come back to ask if something doesn't work. Pls also read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
create or replace procedure <procedure_name> (op in number,[other parameters])
    as 
    begin
    if op = 1 then 
    --insert query
    elsif op = 2 then
    --delete query
    elsif op = 3 then 
    --select query
    elsif op = 4 then
    --update query
    end if;
    end;
```

Hope this helps !

```
create or replace procedure my_try(op in number,
    n1 number default null,nm1 varchar2 default null,
    n2 out number )
    as 
    begin
    if op = 1 then 
    insert into temp1 values(n1,nm1);
    commit;
    elsif op = 2 then
    delete from temp1 where id = n1;
    commit;
    elsif op = 3 then 
    select id into n2 from temp1;
    end if;
    end;
```

Comment: amanji i found this error  ERROR at line 42: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   if
2. op in number,
3. ID int ,
4. NAME VARCHAR2(10),
5. ADDRESS VARCHAR2(10),
6. COMPANY VARCHAR2(10),

Comment: So look at line 42 and address the syntax error there.

Comment: This is just a syntax of writing your requirements. For entering optional parameters , see the edited example (my sample working procedure)

Comment: And for calling the procedure use "=>" . For more details about this operator go through this link : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/08_subs.htm